# Character comparison happens work in C

Tags: c

Suppose you have a string like eg `char str[10]` and you are comparing lets, say

```
if(str[i]>str[i+1])
{
  // some lines of code
}
```

how do they compare, does the compiler converts the character into their ASCII ? Want to know the how character-comparison happens in C.

Comment: The `char` type can be converted into an 8-bit int.  So the comparison is just like comparing normal `int`.

Comment: chars are converted to integers that have the ASCII value of the char

Comment: No, there is no conversion, they are *already* ASCII codes (assuming your implementation uses ASCII).

Comment: But pay attention to the sign... Actually `char` is nothing but a signed 8-bit integer type. Thus converting from `char` to `int` will cause a sign extension. This sometimes leads to bugs.

Comment: The only way the compiler is involved is if `str` is initialized using a literal string in your C source code. In that case, it reads your source file using the encoding that you say the source file uses and converts it to the encoding that you say you want it to be (the "execution character set"). If you aren't telling the compiler these things explicitly, it is using defaults. See your compiler switches and documentation. Tip: neither is likely to be ASCII, but are likely to be some specific superset of ASCII. It might be very valuable to know what that is.

Comment: @WhatsUp: `char` is not necessarily signed, neither is it necessarily 8 bit wide.

Comment: @chqrlie Well, you are talking about "academical C“, while I was pointing out a practical tip...

Comment: `char` can be made unsigned by default on most modern compilers and such a choice is quite reasonable. `char` is a small integer type with an implementation defined range of at least 256 values. If the system uses ASCII, the character `o` has a value of `111`.

Answer (score 1):

If I say

```
char str[] = "Hello, world!";
int i = 7;
printf("%d %d\n", str[i], str[i+1]);
if(str[i] > str[i+1]) { printf("it is greater\n"); }
```

it will print

```
119 111
it is greater
```

But there is nothing "magic" going on here, and there are no special conversions, either.  In C, a character is simply represented by a small integer giving the value of the character in the machine's character set, which for all intents and purposes we can assume will be ASCII (or maybe its superset, Unicode).  And as any ASCII chart will tell you, 'o' is 111 and 'w' is 119.

Comment: Assuming ASCII is abusive but not risky, assuming Unicode is probably incorrect, especially if `char` is signed by default.